# Can I refer/use existing release as part of new release pipeline i am creating?

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I have release pipeline which I am using to deploy the code , however I have to reuse few tasks which are already there in other release pipeline, so to avoid duplication is there any way that i can add existing release pipeline to the new one on top of other tasks , instead of adding same tasks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [task group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=azure-devops), which allows you to encapsulate a sequence of tasks, already defined in a build or a release pipeline, into a single reusable task that can be added to a build or release pipeline, just like any other task.

Comment: Thanks ,sounds like perfect solution , will give it a shot